# jQuery: test regex pattern of class

Tags: jquery, regex, parent

Heyho,

I'd like to adress the parent elements of different paragraphs. Cause the paragraphs are nested in a different way I cannot adress the same way by using "closest" or sth..

That's why I try to use regex testing to adress `#text-test` AND `#img-test`:

```
<div class="text-test">
    <p class"tester">texttest</p>
</div>
<div class="img-test">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="tester">imgtest</p>  
   </div>
</div>

$('.tester').click(function() {
    //$(this).closest('div').addClass('active');
    /* get the closest div where the class ends up with -test
    * and add class active 
    * wrapperdiv = $(this).closest('div').attr('class').test(/-test$/);
    */
    //console.log(wrapperdiv)
});
```

Do you have an advice how I could adress by using the test-method?

Cheers

Comment: Are you aware that you can select the parent of an element with $(this).parent() in jquery? EDIT: I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('div[class$="-test"]').addClass('active');
```

`[name$=value]` called **[End with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)**. For above case, which will select those `div`, whose class end with `-test`.

Comment: hello, thx for your solution, it works, but has one last "mistake": around my markup I wrote about I have another wrapper-div `<div class="content-test"></div>` and with your selector the found element is this outside div.content-test. I would expect that "closest" finds the inner ones :-/ So what could be the reason?

Comment: @ho.s but it should not catch the wrapper div, because `.closest()` will stop searching when first match occur. see demo http://jsfiddle.net/MeeMs/1/